# Selenium button click gives 500 internal server error

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on testing 1 page in which user can add multiple tables in separate divs. For each table there are options to view/edit/delete. I am able to click on edit and delete and proceed with the test. But when trying to click on view, i m getting 500 internal server error. But if I test this on localhost it works.

This is how I find element, using XPATH
//*[text()='"Sample table"']/parent::*/div[2]/div/a[1]

I am trying to run application inside docker workspace. If I run test on localhost, I dont see the error.

This is what i see in page source.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Server Error (500)</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I print current url, the correct URL is also shown, but after searching a lot, I am not getting help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: yes @Prophet. Thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely NOT a Selenium issue.
`500 internal server error` is a 100% server side error.
In case this is your company internal site / page / application you should talk with your BackEnd developers.

Comment: What error would occur if a user is blocked? Would it still be an internal server error?

Comment: AFAIK it will be 4xx, but it is still not a Selenium issue. It is still caused by a server side.

Comment: There have been many 500 errors thrown at me during scraping when manually browsing on that same site works perfectly fine. That doesn't sound exclusively like a server error

Comment: The topic starter wrote this error occurs in a docker workspace while on local host it works correct. What case are you talking about?